# Content Security Policy: SVG from Inkscape with Sozi animation in embed tag

Tags: .htaccess, svg, embed, content-security-policy, inkscape

On my website, I've got an animated SVG created with Sozi in an embed tag as the header image.

My .htacess file CSP header looks like this:
  Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'"

Obviously, this isn't enough to work.

Chrome helpfully offers me about 50 different hash sums for all the elements in the SVG, a bit like this

"Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-OXKUzBwllYUKQyK1cDvFciYCgedWl0Tn33OfzW6sO0U='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback."

Is there a way to whitelist the whole SVG file instead of each element in it that has an inline style? It just doesn't make sense to me to have to copy-paste all those hash sums, when this could be summarized somehow for the whole thing.

I have already tried hashing the SVG, and inserting that in the style-src part of the header, but that didn't work, unfortunately. Using 'unsafe-inline' works (for style-src), but it's not what I want to use, if possible.

Converting Inkscape's inline styles (as was suggested somewhere I can't find again right now) is another option, but it's also not what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no way to whitelist the entire SVG content. If you keep the inline styles and want a secure policy, then the policy must specify all the hashes the browser shows, or else you must use nonces.

There’s otherwise no way browsers can “summarize the whole thing”. Since the point of using CSP for this case is to ensure browsers can distinguish between the inline styles you intentionally added to the document yourself versus styles that you didn’t (and so which may have been added by an attacker), then without you specifying a hash or nonce for each inline style instance, there’s no way browsers can otherwise determine which are which.

Answer (score 0):

With SVGs, everything you use in a style attribute can also be expressed as an attribute.

This is less relevant to you, because you're using a tool to produce your SVGs, but for anyone editing them by hand. If you're getting an error on something like `<rect style="fill: red" />`, you can correct that by doing `<rect fill="red">` which is CSP valid under strict rules and will render the same. Do this for all style attributes and you can have SVGs working under the strictest of CSP rule sets.